# Saving a proprietary file to Dropbox using Document Interaction

Tags: ios, dropbox

I'm trying to save a custom file with my extension to Dropbox using DocumentInteractionController. Dropbox does show up in the DocumentInteractionController's "Open In" menu when my file has a recognized extension such as .txt. There were a number of related topics which I tried to follow. One example: [Associating my app's custom file in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9434574/associating-my-apps-custom-file-in-ios).

The following shows my UIExportedTypeDeclarations:

```
<key>UIExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UITypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.mysite.myapp.myext</string>
        <key>UITypeDescription</key>
        <string>My Special File</string>
        <key>UITypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <string>myext</string>
            <key>public.mime-type</key>
            <string>application/octet-stream</string>
        </dict>
        <key>UITypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.data</string>
            <string>public.content</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

I'm not even sure that Dropbox looks at the ConformsTo or even the TagSpecification. It did show up in the Open In menu when I was testing a .txt file and inadvertantly left "myextension" for the public.filename-extension key. So perhaps my thinking about the UIExportedTypeDeclarations, or my expectations about Dropbox file handling, is off base. Any help will be appreciated. I'm spinning my wheels. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Spelling error: UIExportedTypeDeclaration is not UTExportedTypeDeclaration. A little too much UIKit on the brain. Fixing the spelling fixed the problem. Of course all the tags needed to be fixed.